# Flutter Firebase error - Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app in play store, `recaptcha` started coming in phone auth from this morning. This is when I looked at the error.

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid request fields in play_integrity_token ]

> SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 Invalid request fields in play_integrity_token

I didn't change anything.

**I checked these things**

- SHA certificate fingerprints & package name -
  It's ok. same in play console and firebase project
- Play Integrity API status - Integration active (Below picture)

[image]

**What I did :**

- Download `google-services.json` and replace it. But not worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After publishing new version of mobile app on play store, `recaptcha` removed automatically.